# Overlay прозрачность

Tags: javascript

Как на нативном JS реализовать эффект прозрачности как в слоях в PS - Overlay и Multiply?

Comment: Вы о чём? Браузер? Нода? Картинки или html?

Comment: Картинки. Браузер. т.е. наложение одной картинки на другую.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes поможет?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode